# How to reference the section of a figure or table (on purpose!)

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

Is there a way to reference the section in which  a particular figure or table is defined? I know that referencing a figure's section is typically a mistake  (i.e., accidentally putting the `\label{}` before the caption) but I want to do it on purpose and, of course, by putting the `\label{}` after the caption.

I guess I'm looking for some type of `\sectionof{myfig}` command that doesn't exist.

Comment: In LaTeX, the basic `\label` directive, when applied to an object of any type other than `section`, does not keep track of the section number associated with the object being `label`-ed. If having this information is important to you, you may want to look into the [zref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/zref) package to create customized `\zlabel` and `\zref` instructions.

Comment: Just out of interest, if it did work, why couldn't you put the `\label` before the `\caption`?

Comment: @cfr Because sometimes I want to do reference the float itself, and other times the section in which that float occurs... though I suppose I could put two labels; one before, one after.

Comment: Well, you could use two labels in that case. I mean, if it worked, you could. Since it doesn't, it is a merely hypothetical suggestion, of course.

Comment: I have added a possible solution, could you give some feedback please?

Answer (score 2):

This applies the very sophisticated package `zref` by Heiko Oberdiek, which extends the labelling/reference system tremendously.

Labels have `property` lists, as such, the figure label should have a `figsection` property, which contains the section number in which the figure label is generated.

```
\makeatletter
\zref@newlist{section}  % define a larger list of section properties
\zref@newprop{figsection}[undefined]{\number\value{section}} % define the property `figsection` and store the section number. 
\zref@addprop{section}{figsection} % couple figsection to section list
\newcommand{\figsectionlabel}[1]{%  Wrapper for `\zref@label..
  \label{#1}% Set a traditional label
  \zref@labelbylist{#1}{section}  % Add the label #1 to the property list section  % Basically a hook is executed
}%

\newcommand{\sectionof}[1]{%
\zref@extract{#1}{figsection}%  Wrapper 
}

\makeatother
```

---

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage[user]{zref}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{cleveref}



\makeatletter
\zref@newlist{section}
\zref@newprop{figsection}[undefined]{\number\value{section}}
\zref@addprop{section}{figsection}
\newcommand{\figsectionlabel}[1]{%
  \label{#1}% Set a traditional label
  \zref@labelbylist{#1}{section}  % Add the label #1 to the property list section
}%

\newcommand{\sectionof}[1]{%
\zref@extract{#1}{figsection}%
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}



\chapter{My sophisticated \LaTeX\ code}

Figure \ref{secondfig} is placed in Section \sectionof{secondfig} and \ref{fourthfig} can be found in \sectionof{fourthfig}

\section{First} \label{firstsec}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Some dummy figure} \label{firstfig}
\end{figure}


\section{Two}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Some dummy figure Nr. 2} \figsectionlabel{secondfig}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Some dummy figure Nr. 3} \label{thirdfig}
\end{figure}


\section{Three}

\section{Four}

\section{Five}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Some dummy figure Nr. 4} \figsectionlabel{fourthfig}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]